# Android studio console not displaying messages

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm attempting to debug a thrown exception, but I'm not receiving log messages. In my console, the only message I receive is when my emulator connects or disconnects. What's odd to me is, after some error, my app stays open and usable. Though what ever changes that were involved in the error aren't completed. Even when I call assert false, my app stays usable. These problems started when I updated to Android Studio Hedgehog.

I've tried invalidating my caches, cold-booting, a new device, and enabling "show logcat automatically".

I'm not familiar with logcat, but I tried using it's window instead. However, it was not useful since it only shows the exceptions you've explicitly logged. I've read that google or firebase analytics may interfere with logging, but I'm only using firebase and I disabled it.

Comment: Are you sure you're running a build that has logging enabled?  For example, release builds usually don't spit out logs, unless you explicitly make so.

Comment: @IvánGarzaBermea I looked into and my app is a debug build. I managed to solve my problems with logcat, but my console still shows nothing. But that's enough for me to work with.

Answer (score 0):

[android-studio-write-and-view-logs-with-logcat](https://winjia.medium.com/android-studio-write-and-view-logs-with-logcat-5e7bd4c4a030)

This article might help you in using logcat more efficiently, and check the logcat filter make sure you do not have a filter applied that might be excluding the message you are looking for and provide more information like how are you printing your log statements ?

Comment: I learned more specifically, that I don't see assertions and unhandled exceptions thrown in background threads. Even with no filter, it's not there. I write my logs using Log.d() and the like. But I'm trying to track things like Nullpointer, which I wouldn't log. Though, other things I log in the background do work.

Answer (score 0):

I did not fix my issues with the console, but I was able to get logcat to work instead.
It turns out, I was "submitting" my tasks to an ExecutorService instead of "executing" them. The former, wraps exceptions the results in a Future object, so I was not seeing them in my logs.